# PHP: preg_match_all consider two equal matches as one

Tags: php

I want to extract some of the data from a string (HTML, actually). I searched a bit and found preg_match_all. The issue is that if there are two equal matches, the function considers them as two and make space for both. My code, code's output and code's expected output will clearly explain.

```
<?php
    $html = "
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang=\"en\">
        <head>
            <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src=\"[profileLink@user:0]\" />
            <img src=\"[profileLink@user:0]\" />
        </body>
        </html>
    ";
    $regex = "/\[(.*?)@(.*?)\]/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '[profileLink@user:0]' (length=20) // It looks ok
      1 => string '[profileLink@user:0]' (length=20) // Don't want it.
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'profileLink' (length=11) // It looks ok
      1 => string 'profileLink' (length=11) // Don't want it.
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'user:0' (length=6) // It looks ok
      1 => string 'user:0' (length=6) // Don't want it.
```

**Expected output:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '[profileLink@user:0]' (length=20)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'profileLink' (length=11)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'user:0' (length=6)
```

Comment: That's what `preg_match_all` does. When you have your resulting array you could easily remove duplcates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of `preg_match_all`, the outcome will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "[profileLink@user:0]"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "profileLink"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "user:0"
}
```

Comment: No, it will be more pain. I think I will have to stick to @Jonathon's suggestion. BTW, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @MuhammedTalhaAkbar Well, based on the example of your question it seems to remove the "pain", but things might be different in your proper code.